# Disabled SIP on mac won't allow me to modify permissions settings in /SYSTEM/Library

Tags: permissions, privileges, macos-catalina

I am trying to add a file in /SYSTEM/Library.

1. I've restarted the mac in recovery mode.
2. Ran `csrutil disable` in Terminal.
3. Logged back in and tried to copy the file in /SYSTEM/Library only to be denied as if SIP was still enabled.

I even tried to change permissions on the whole SYSTEM folder by adding a user read/write privileges only to get 
"The operation can't be completed because you don't have the necessary permission."

Comment: Catalina's System drive is read only, disabling SIP doesn't unlock it. use the user library instead, that's what it's for.

Comment: @Tetsujin - using user library wouldn't work in all cases.  Perhaps you want to update logon screen wallpaper by replacing `/System/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina.heic` with your own picture for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with macOS 10.15 Catalina the system volume is read-only.  See this Apple support page [About the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650)

To change files in */System/Library/* therefore, after [disabling SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) from recovery, boot into your normal macOS environment and remount the system volume read-write with `sudo mount -uw /`

```
[admin@macOS] / $csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
[admin@macOS] / $sudo touch /System/Library/testfile
touch: /System/Library/testfile: Read-only file system
[admin@macOS] / $sudo mount -uw /
[admin@macOS] / $sudo touch /System/Library/testfile
[admin@macOS] / $sudo rm /System/Library/testfile
```

If you want to update the file using *Finder* rather than *Terminal* once you have re-mounted the system volume you must also enter `killall Finder` (note case matters so capital `F` for `Finder`).

The read-write mount option only applies to the current session - when you reboot it will again mount as read-only.

Alternatively you can add/update/delete your file by mounting the system volume from recovery or another instance of macOS.

Comment: So do I  have to do this while in recovery mode and add my file as well before rebooting again in order to maintain the read-write session active?

Comment: Or can it be done in a regular session in terminal?

Comment: You first have to disable SIP in recovery (like you did). Then boot into normal macOS environment and the above was done in a regular terminal session.  I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.